# Many times coming from child view to parent view cause memory issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I dismiss current ViewController and come to parent ViewController, many times I face excess bad exception. So what precautions should I take while coding? I know it is due to memory leak.

Comment: Well isn't that a pity...could you please show the tracelog?

Comment: Bad excess means you are trying to interact with Deallocated object :-/
Can you show us how do you dismiss and show your viewControllers

Comment: please put some code here..

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a memory leak because you're `UIViewControllers` are not really dismissed and you create everytime a new one. You should print the memory address to debug log and try to call them later to check if they still exist and if the memory address will change on each new creation.

Try to f[ollow the part of unwinding](http://www.absoluteripple.com/resources/using-ios-storyboard-segues) `segues`. This should do it. Maybe there is another problem in your code.

Comment: you mean to say when i comes to parent view controller the variables of parent view deallocated can i made them strong property so it will not happen

Comment: print `self` but you shouldn't have a `description` method inside so you'll get the memory address of this viewcontroller. You can also do it in `prepareForSegue:` by printing the `destinationViewController`. Then break after 3 or 4 times inside the `prepareForSegue` and `po` the memory addresses of the previous `UIViewController`. if it's not null they don't get dismissed